# Two way data binding in dom-repeater

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create a two way data binding between inputs in a dom-repeater and the template but changes seem to not propagate back. What am I doing wrong?

```
<dom-module id="record-card">
    <template id="node">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{labels}}">
            <h1>
                <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{item}}" on-change="labelsChanged">
            </h1>
        </template>
        <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{labels.0}}">
        Labels: <span>{{labels}}</span>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "record-card",
    properties: {
        labels: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true,
            value: function() {
                return ["Pizza", "Person"]
            }
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

The input in the dom repeater doesn't propagate, the input outside of it using the path propagates into the repeater but not the other way around but it doesn't update the `{{}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question ([How to two-way bind iron-input to dom-repeat's item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748691)) and the answer I got was to use `value="{{item::input}}`. However, it seems like binding to a raw array of strings is not working very well. I tried changing it to an array of objects with a single string property and that did it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/X6b3FqZIY29tiGYoHnzq

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, I tried commenting on yours but am not allowed yet. I'll check if this works...

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it out, it only works if it is objects, so here comes the serialisation train. Thanks though.
Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1821#issuecomment-110804603

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I deal with data changed in nested dom-repeat

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0P5vNxg46t5fX7gJFxU?p=preview

```
// Add Task to the selected Employee
_addTask: function() {
 var i=this._getSelectedEmployeeIndex()
 if (i>=0) {
   var employee = this.employees[i]
   // use both for child dom-repeat
   this.push('employees.'+i+'.tasks', {name: this._random(this.__tasks)})
   this.notifyPath('employees.'+i+'.tasks.*')
 }
},
```